# Future value of annuinities

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image]

I tried $5000(1 + 0.04)^{10}$ and got $7401.22

The correct is $60,030.50

Why such differences?

*EDIT*

Ok I see my mistake. so now, this is what I did

5000 * 1.04 = 5200..y1

5200 + 5000 = 10200

10200 * 1.04 = 10608 y1.5

10608 + 5000 = 15608

15608 * 1.04 = 16,232.32 y2

16232.32 + 5000 = 21232.32

21232.32 * 1.04 = 22081.6128 y2.5

22081.6128 + 5000 = 27081.6128

27081.6128 * 1.04 = 28164.87731 y3

28164.87731 + 5000 = 33164.87731

...etc and I kept repeating for 5 years..

but my final answer was $62, 431.76704

The correct answer is $60,030.50

I don't know what to do

Answer (score 1):

There are two deposits per year for five years, so ten deposits of 5000, meaning that the accumulated value is clearly going to be greater than 50000.  Your expression computes an accumulated value of a **single** payment after 5 years at a rate of 8% compounded semiannually (i.e., 4% per six months).

---

The customary method of calculating present value and accumulated value of annuities or general cash flows is to regard each payment separately and calculate its value at the time point of interest.  For example, if $5000$ was paid on 6/30 in the first year, then by the end of the fifth year, it has had a total of 9 semi-annual periods to accrue interest.  The final payment of $5000$ has not had any time to accrue interest.

So, we can regard the accumulated value of the series of payments as $$5000(1.04)^9 + 5000(1.04)^8 + \cdots + 5000(1.04) + 5000.$$  This in turn can be written as $$5000 \frac{(1.04)^{10} - 1}{1.04 - 1} = 60030.50,$$ as claimed.  The formula we used was that for a finite geometric series:  if the interest is $j$ per period, and level payments of $K$ are made at the **end** of each period, the accumulated value at the end of the $n^{\rm th}$ period is $$K s_{\overline{n}\rceil j} = K \frac{(1+j)^n - 1}{j}.$$  For $K = 5000$, $j = 0.04$, and $n = 10$, we get the above result.

So, why did you get a wrong answer?  The value you calculated corresponds to exactly $1.04$ times $60030.50$.  In other words, you compounded the fund for one additional period of six months.  The statement of the problem is not very precise, but what it intends to say is that payments are made at the end of every six-month period (6/30 and 12/31), and the number of years that elapse should be counted from the beginning of that calendar year, not from the time that the first payment was made.

Comment: updated my question